# Module Not found error: office365 not found

Tags: python, sharepoint, module, pip, office365

I have seen this issue with some resolutions already, but none have worked for my issue. I have pip installed the latest version of `office365(v 2.2.0)` to my knowledge using the command:

```sh
pip install office365-rest-client
```

I am trying to import using the following lines of code:

```py
    from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
    from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
    from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File
```

I receive the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'office365'
```

Just to test it out, I uninstalled and reinstalled pandas, then successfully imported pandas into my project.

Comment: when you type 'pip list', do you see the package in the output?

Comment: Yes i do. I also see O365 (which also fails to import) from another attempt at getting these packages into my program. O365 produces the same error.

Comment: Try this, in the terminal type "python" to open the RPEL. Then try to import office 365 there and see if you get the same error. Make sure that you are in the same directory that you where when you install office 365 with pip.

Comment: Maybe `pip3 install` instead of `pip install`?

Answer (score 24):

Install `office365-REST-Python-Client` and `office365` with the following commands:

```bash
pip install office365-REST-Python-Client
pip install office365
```

After that, restart your IDE and re-import the packages.

If you're installing to an environment that's not on your local machine, you can add the `python -m` prefix to ensure it gets installed in the correct location.

Comment: I also had to install one other package:       pip install office365-rest-client

Answer (score 5):

ATTENTION - You must make the letter O lowercase in both install commands, as below. Capital O does not work.

pip install office365-REST-Python-Client
pip install office365

Answer (score 2):

You also need to install the office365 library as well as office365-rest-client

```
pip install office365
```